# Spring mongo InvalidPersistentPropertyPath with @Version

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I was migrating from spring boot 2.0.0 to 2.1.1. After migrating one of the several issues that I am facing is the InvalidPersistentPropertyPath for documents with certain fields and @version. This used to work previuosly with  Spring boot 2.0.0

Below is the sample document that I want to save in mongo db:

```
@Document
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Report  implements Serializable {
    @Id
    protected String id;

    @NotNull
    @Field("ReportName")
    protected String reportName;

    @Field("IA1Value")
    private Long iA1Value = 0L;

    @Field("IA2Value")
    private Long iA2Value = 0L;

    @Version
    private Long version;

    public Report(String reportName) {
        this.reportName = reportName;
    }

}
```

I wrote a test case to read and save to the mongo DB.

> org.springframework.data.mapping.context.InvalidPersistentPropertyPath:
>   No property 'IA1Value' found on class
>   com.experiments.migration.mongo.Report! Did you mean:
>   IA2Value,IA1Value,iA2Value,iA1Value?

But if the @Version is commented it works....

I would like to know what the relation is with @Version.

The entire sample is there in :

https://github.com/KencyK/spring-boot-migration

NOTE : Please **DO NOT** suggest to keep the field name. Coz i know that would fix it. I would like to know why this works if I remove the @Version.

Also I have tried with older version of Lombok which was used in spring boot 2.0.0

Comment: try putting your `version` field declaration above ` iA1Value`

Comment: @ErfanAhmed Even after putting version field above, the issue is NOT fixed.

Comment: the `iA1Value` and `iA2Value` is set `0L` and `reportName` is set by constructor. Why there is no *getter, setter* method on your class? give a try by assigning getter setter method for `version`.

Comment: I am using lombok here. The report class is annotated with @Data which will create the getters and setters for all your fields. I have anyways tried what you have suggested and as i had expected it still does not work. This used to work with spring boot 2.0.0

Comment: try another test case, instead of `@Version` annotation use `@Field` annotation for `version` field. see if it works or not. If works then try adding both annotations.

Comment: Removing @ Version works as i have already mentioned.. But we need the @ Version. Anyways the other suggestion also does not work.